Question on the $\operatorname{LCM}$ method for finding period of sum of two periodic functions?
We are supposed to find the period of the sum of two periodic functions $f(x)$ with period $F$ and $g(x)$ with period $G$. The general rule is that the period of the total function $f(x)+g(x)$ will be $\operatorname{LCM} (F,G)$.
However, this method may not give the shortest period in some cases. For instance, if $f(x)=|\cos x|$ and $g(x)=|\sin x|$, then period of $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ by$\operatorname{LCM} (F,G)$ is $\pi$, but, shortest period of $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is indeed $\frac{\pi}2$. In this example, the $\operatorname{LCM}$ method gives the second (or even multiple of the shortest) period of $h(x)$.
My question:

Can it happen (for some other examples) that the $\operatorname{LCM}$ method gives the third (or odd multiple of the shortest) period of $h(x)$? or, does it always give either the shortest or the even multiple of the shortest one? I appreciate any potential counterexample that the $\operatorname{LCM}$ method gives the odd multiple of the shortest period.


It is possible that the sum of the two functions is a constant, in which case there is no minimum period.

Try this:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\lvert\sin(x)\rvert & 3n\pi \leq x \leq (3n+1)\pi,\ n\in\mathbb Z, \\
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & 3n\pi \leq x \leq (3n+1)\pi,\ n\in\mathbb Z, \\
\lvert\sin(x)\rvert & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have period $3\pi,$ but $f(x) + g(x)$ has period $\pi.$
Replace $3$ in the definitions of $f$ and $g$ with any other integer greater than $1$ to get a different ratio of periods.

If you want something a little more elegant (not piecewise),
$$
f(x) = \sin(3x) + \sin(x), \\
g(x) = \sin(3x) - \sin(x).
$$
